# Is it possible to understand and use Relationships and Contextual Filters without knowing SQL?

Tags: views

Are there any good, layman descriptions of contextual filters and relationships for those site builders that aren't developers?

Is it possible to be comfortable with Relationships and Contextual Filters without knowing SQL? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By knowing SQL you can have better understanding but it is not necessary.

> Relationships give you information about entities that are not listed in the fields b joining current content with other entities. For example detail information about the author of the node is not in the fields, Only it's uid is in there, so by selecting author as relationships you can get the rest of the information.
>
> Contextual filters are similar to regular filters in that you can use mainly the same fields to filter the records on. Where contextual filters differ greatly is that you do not set the filtering value when you create the View, but it is taken from context. Contextual filters are great for when the View needs to display content dynamically depending on various contextual conditions